# A (not) far cry from something

Tags: american-english, british-english

I wonder if there is an idiomatic expression to say that something recalls a former model. I like the "far cry" expression, does it work also in the negative form?

> Our God is but/not a far cry from Zeus's old and beardy figure.

Any thought?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes. It does work in the negative.

Answer (score 1):

A [Google NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=far%20cry%20from%2Cnot%20a%20far%20cry%20from&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfar%20cry%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20a%20far%20cry%20from%3B%2Cc0) querying works published in English for instances of *not a far cry from* versus the non-negated form shows vastly different patterns of use:

[image]

That *not a far cry from* registers at all means the construction occurs at least forty times in the entire Google Books corpus, but apparently not enough to move it much past zero. This suggests that a not insignificant number of readers will never have encountered the negative of *far cry* and their attention will be drawn far more to your use of the expression than what you mean by it.

Saying *a not insignificant number* to suggest a number that is indeed significant employs a figure of speech called [*litotes*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litotes), a kind of understatement negating a quality to suggest its opposite:

> not a bad idea         *That's a good idea*
>   not the cleanest lake       *It's polluted.*
>   not an easy task          *It's difficult.*

You are attempting to use the same figure of speech by negating *a far cry* to suggest nearness: a concept of God you designate as "our" is close to "old and beardy" Zeus.

The problem is that *a far cry from* indicates a vast difference between two things, and without further context, a reader does not know how far you wish to bridge that vast difference by negating it. Do you want to say that the difference between "our" image of God is not all that vast but still significant? Or do you wish to say that the two are actually close?

If the latter is your intention, then you are better served with:

> Our image of God is not far from Zeus's old and beardy figure.